# Output of awk in color

Tags: awk, colors, echo

I am trying to set up polybar on my newly-installed Arch system. I know very little bash scripting. I am just getting started. If this is not an appropriate question for this forum, I will gladly delete it. I want to get the following `awk` output in color:

```
sensors | grep "Package id 0:" | tr -d '+' | awk '{print $4}'"
```

I know how to do this with echo, so I tried to pass the output so that with the echo command, it would be rendered in color:

```
sensors | grep "Package id 0:" | tr -d '+' | awk '{print $4}' | echo -e "\e[1;32m ???? \033[0m"
```

where I want to put the appropriate information where the `???` are.

The `awk output` is just a temperature, something like this: `50.0°C`.

edit: It turns out that there is a very easy way to pass colors to outputs of bash scripts (even python scripts too) in polybar. But I am still stumped as to why the solutions suggested here in the answers work in the terminal but not in the polybar modules. I have several custom modules that use scripts with no problems.

Comment: please update the question to show your attempt to pass the data to `echo`; also, providing the raw output from `sensors` may be helpful to understand the data we're dealing with

Comment: are you dealing with a single line of output, or multiple lines of output? and if multiple lines of output, do you want them printed on separate colored lines or altogther (space delimited?) on a single line of colored output?

Comment: kindly do post output of `sensors` command once in your question along with desired sample output to make your question more clear, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `awk`

```
$ sensors | awk '/Package id 0:/{gsub(/+/,""); print "\033[32m"$4"\033[0m"}'
```

If that does not work, you can try this approach;

```
$ sensors | awk -v color="$(tput setaf 2)" -v end="$(tput sgr0)" '/Package id 0:/{gsub(/+/,""); print color $4 end}'
```

Comment: Can you explain the syntax in gsub and how it is being used? I understand what awk is doing, but where is a global substitution being made? Please excuse the ignorance. I am the noobiest of noobs. OT: I am a mathematician by training and post and read frequently to math stack, and over there, they're pretty ruthless. It's nice to see that here, people are more laid-back. Thank you.

Comment: Both of these suggestions work in the terminal, but not when I run them in a polybar module as a custom script. I have several other custom modules with bash scripts, all of which run fine. When I launch polybar (either from i3 or the terminal, this is what I get (see next comment).

Comment: killall polybar ┬─[paul@:~]─[21:10:20] ╰─>$ polybar notice: Parsing config file: /home/paul/.config/polybar/config.ini error: /home/paul/.config/polybar/config.ini:117: Value 'sensors | awk '/Package id 0:/{gsub(/+/,""); print "\033[32m"$4 "°C" "\033[0m"}'' of key 'exec' contains one or more unescaped backslashes, please prepend them with the backslash escape character.

Comment: In the terminal, it runs fine: (I added the °C to the script):  ┬─[paul@:~]─[21:27:10]
╰─>$ cd ~/.config/custom-scripts/
┬─[paul@:~/.config/custom-scripts]─[21:27:15]
╰─>$ ./cpu-temp2.sh
 47.0°C

Comment: @Matematleta In your original code, you had `tr -d '+'`, without sample data, I do not know what it is replacing, but, `gsub` or maybe `sub` achieves the same thing as your code, but all within a single pass rather than 3.

Comment: Very good ! ```tail -n 3 -f /usr/local/var/log/nginx/*.log -f /usr/local/var/log/php*.log | awk  '/^==> / {a=substr($0, 5, length-8); next} {print "-""\033[32m" a":""\033[0m"$0"\n" }'

```

Answer (score 2):

This is where you want to capture the output of awk. Since awk can do what grep and tr do, I've integrated the pipeline into one awk invocation:

```sh
temp=$(sensors | awk '/Package id 0:/ {gsub(/\+/, ""); print $4}')
echo -e "\e[1;32m $temp \033[0m"
```

Comment: Thank you. It runs fine in the terminal, which is fish, so I changed the beginning because = is not supported. ─[paul@:~/.config/custom-scripts]─[21:31:52]
╰─>$ set temp $(sensors | awk '/Package id 0:/ {gsub(/\+/, ""); print $4}')
     echo -e "\e[1;32m $temp \033[0m" 
 46.0

But when I put it in my polybar module, and run it, I get this: 

[1;32m 45.0 [0m in the default color white.